# Sortear um item da Lista, e depois sortear outro item de uma lista com o nome que foi sorteado da primeira lista

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Bom dia pessoal.
Tenho uma Lista principal chamada `"Livros"`.
Preciso sortear um nome dentro dessa lista `Livros`.

Depois de escolher um dos nomes, preciso sortear novamente, mas agora preciso escolher de outra lista, e essa segunda lista tem o nome da que foi sorteada primeiramente.

Para esclarecer.
na Lista `Livros` tenho `("Lucas" e "Isaias")`

Suponhamos que a escolha aleatoria foi `Lucas`
Então meu programa tem que fazer outra escolha aleatoria dentro dessa outra lista chama `Lucas` que tem os valores `Lucas1 e Lucas2`.

Por ultimo vamos supor que entre `"Lucas1" e "Lucas2"` foi escolhido o `"Lucas1"`

La embaixo tenho um dicionario chamado `"Lucas1", com as chaves "1", "2" e "3"`
a ultima coisa que quero
É que meu programa escolha uma dessas chaves e printe o seu valor.
Se escolheu `"1" : "Text1"`  quero que printe isso..
Depois eu adapto para o que eu precisar.
Tentei diversas formas, pesquisei mas nao consegui encontrar a solução. Agradeço a todos

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import *

#Turple Ordered and Unchangeable
Livros = ("Lucas", "Isaias")


Lucas = ("Lucas1", "Lucas2")
Isaias = ("Isaias1", "Isaias2")

Lucas1 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4"
}

Lucas2 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4" 
}

Isaias1 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4"
}


Isaias2 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4"
}


print("How to Random ? ")
```

Comment: Você fez mais alguma coisa ou só criou as listas e tal?

Comment: Eu tentei diversas coisas, tentei alguns metodos, mas nao funcionaram, sorteavam primeiro a lista corretamente, mas ai depois no segundo sorteio só me trazia uma letra...
Pesquisei , mas nada parecido com o que estou tentando fazer.
Resumindo eu tentei tentei e não cheguei a lugar nenhum, isso foi mais complicado do que imaginei que seria

Comment: por exemplo aqui, ele escolhe a primeira lista e depois ele escolhe soh uma letra daquele livro, mas eu nao queria assim.

``` LivroEscolha = choice(Livros)
print(LivroEscolha)

CapEscolha = choice(LivroEscolha)
print(CapEscolha)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma sugestão é você eliminar esse intermédio entre as listas, para não precisar ter algo que relacione o "Lucas" de uma tabela com o "Lucas1" "Lucas2" de outras.

Você pode fazer isso fazendo listas de listas, e ir fazendo o random.choice sequencialmente em cada camada delas. Para isso modifiquei só precisei modificar a ordem em que elas eram declaradas, e modifiquei para conterem os elementos mencionados anteriormente no código.

Na camada mais inferior, você escolheu usar um dicionário. Neste caso, como você precisa fazer o random.choice em uma lista, podemos fazer o random só no `list(dicionario.keys())` e pegar a chave ou valor relacionado a este sorteio.
Veja o código exemplo:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random

Lucas1 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4"
}

Lucas2 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4" 
}

Isaias1 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4"
}

Isaias2 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4"
}

Lucas = (Lucas1, Lucas2)
Isaias = (Isaias1, Isaias2)

Livros = (Lucas, Isaias)

NomeEscolhido=random.choice(Livros)
SegundaEscolha=random.choice(NomeEscolhido)
entradaNoDicionarioEscolhida=random.choice(list(SegundaEscolha.keys()))
#print(entradaNoDicionarioEscolhida) #Caso queira printar a chave sorteada
print(SegundaEscolha[entradaNoDicionarioEscolhida]) #Caso queira printar o valor
```

Que retornou, em uma execução:

```
Text1
```

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso que procurava, Funcionou perfeitamente.